# How to add text to image and save as new image

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create an Android app that adds a random quote to images.

The general process is this:

1. Start from a custom given image that shows when starting the app.
2. From this image all the user can do is tap on it and generate a new random "quote" that get overlaid on the image.
3. The user can save the newly created image with the quote he chose and set it as wallpaper.

I have got to the point where I can display the image in an ImageView.

My list of quotes is stored in my `strings.xml` file.

Comment: sorry for being too lenghty and not perfectly clear, thanks Thomas.

Comment: Is it just one single image or multiple images? I understood the strings/quotes part. Just want to be clear on the image part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The image is always the same, what can change is the quote printed over it, and this should occur when the user taps on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Francesco my friend, I've an idea although not a working code ('cuz I'm not really good at it). So, here it is:

Implement an `onClickListener()` on your `ImageView` like below:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            /** When I say do your stuff here, I mean read the user input and set your wallpaper here. I'm sorry that I don't really know how to save/set the wallpaper */
        }
    });
```

When it comes to reading user input/generating random quotes, you can do this:

You said you already have the quotes saved in the `strings.xml` file. Using the ids of those strings, I think you can implement a `switch` case scenario where it uses `java imports` - `java.util.Scanner` and `java.util.Random`. Ultimately, using these in your `ImageView` `onClickListener` could/should result in the desired output.

I know my answer is too vague, but I've a faint hope that it has given you a minute lead as to what you can implement. I seriously hope there are better answers than this. If not, then I hope this helps you some, and I also hope that I'm not leading you in the wrong direction since this is just a mere speculation. Sorry, but this is all I've got.

Comment: your answer is actually great also because i tought about the same thing as well. Using random variable that generates me a number between 1 and N (where N is the number of quotes) and associate the text printing to the OnClick event :)

Comment: But i also kind of moved my project logic to just make the application install a new live wallpaper which will do all the work instead of using the application-->generate new quotes-->save the image...what's the point of having just 1 quote per time :)

Answer (score 6):

I do something like this in an app. Use Canvas.

I edited down a piece of my code, which actually adds a couple of other images on the background and stuff too.

Meat of code:

```
private static Bitmap getPoster(...) {
    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, background_id)
        .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(res.getAssets(), FONT_PATH);
    font = Typeface.create(font, Typeface.BOLD);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTypeface(font);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);
    float fontSize = getFontSize(background.getWidth(), THE_QUOTE, paint); //You'll have to define a way to find a size that fits, or just use a constant size.

    paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
    canvas.drawText(THE_QUOTE, (background.getWidth() - paint.measureText(THE_QUOTE)) / 2,
        background.getHeight() - FILLER_HEIGHT, paint); //You might want to do something different. In my case every image has a filler in the bottom which is 50px. 
    return background;
}
```

Put your own version of that in a class and feed it the image id and anything else. It returns a bitmap for you to do whatever you want with (display it in an imageview, let the user save it and set as wallpape).

Answer (score 1):

I know i did this for the PC with imagemagick a few years ago(save image with text on)

Seems like imagemagick have been ported to android, so I would start digging into thier documentation.

https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick